# Can an SDL2 window be always active and ontop of a DirectX window?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

The SDL2 window must constantly be ontop of the directX window regardless if the user is clicking away at the directX or SDL2 window.

Why?

I will use this SDL window to toggle music that I want to listen to while still being able to enjoy my video game.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible without doing some WinAPI calls, but try messing around with SDL_RaiseWindow().

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RaiseWindow